# Ego Graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx, bipartite

I have bipartite graph with nodes such as(a1,a2,...a100, m1,m2,...). I want to find the induced subgraph for certain nodes say(a1,a2 and a10). I can do this by using `networkx.ego_graph`, but it takes one vertex at one time and returns the induced graph. I want to know if there is any way to do this at once for all the nodes that i am interested in and then select the one that is largest.

Comment: Thanks @yatu. This does work correctly. I made a small change to suite my requirements. The Solution looks for highest degree, but i wanted to get the number of nodes in the largest connected component involving nodes in a list say (l = [1,'a',6]]) and there may be other nodes as well connected to these that I have to consider. So i created ego graph for each node in the list and then used Graph.Compose_all to create a subgraph. Then i used the connected_components on the composed graph to get the one with largest length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the general case, the ego graph can be obtained using [`nx.ego_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.ego.ego_graph.html).

Though in your specific case, it looks like you want to find the largest induced `ego graph` in the network. For that you can first find the node with a highest [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)), and then obtain its ego graph.

---

Let's create an example bipartite graph:

```
import networkx as nx

B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'k'], bipartite=1)
B.add_edges_from([(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'a'), 
                  (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (5, 'k'), (6, 'k'), (6, 'j')])


rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 6
nx.draw(B, node_color='lightblue', 
        with_labels=True)
```

[image]

And as mentioned in the question, say we want to select among the following list of nodes:

```
l = [1,'a',6]
```

It looks like you want to select the one that has the *highest centrality degree* among these. For that you could do:

```
deg_l = {i:B.degree(i) for i in l}    
highest_centrality_node = max(deg_l.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

Now we could plot the corresponding `ego_graph` with:

```
ego_g = nx.ego_graph(B, highest_centrality_node)
d = dict(ego_g.degree)
nx.draw(ego_g, node_color='lightblue', 
        with_labels=True, 
        nodelist=d, 
        node_size=[d[k]*300 for k in d])
```

[image]